# Not sure why this code is giving me an error. "i" seems not to be defined, can someone explain this

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I am getting an error where "i" is not defined can someone explain this. How can it be formatted better?

```
'use strict';

var a = 1

for( i = 0; i <= 1; i++ ) {
    var b = a + i;
}

function Math(a) {
    console.log(a, ' + ', b, ' = 3');
}

Math(a);
```

Comment: You said "use strict" so `i` must be explicitly declared.

Answer (score 3):

[Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

> **Strict Mode** is a new feature in ECMAScript 5 that allows you to place a program, or a function, in a "**strict**" operating context. This **strict** context prevents certain actions from being taken and throws more exceptions.

Since you are writing code in ***strict mode***, you have to declare the variable `i` explicitly in the for loop:

```js
'use strict';

var a = 1

for( var i = 0; i <= 1; i++ ) {
    var b = a + i;
}

function Math(a) {
    console.log(a, ' + ', b, ' = 3');
}

Math(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

In strict mode, "assignments, which would accidentally create global variables, instead throw an error"

So you have two options:

1. Disable strict mode by removing `'use strict;'`
2. Declare the `i` variable:

   for( var i = 0; i <= 1; i++ ) {
     var b = a + i;
   }

More about strict mode on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 1):

Since you're `using strict`, `i` must be declared before being used in the for loop.  You can fix this by declaring `i` within for loop like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= 1; i++ ) {
    var b = a + i;
}
```